# how to password protect a folder in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, password, encfs, cryptkeeper

I am new and using **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS**. I want to protect a particular folder with a password. so that no one can access the folder without the password. Is there any software or process to do so? I tired **cryptkeeper** but I failed to install with following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cryptkeeper
```

Comment: I do not know cryptkeeper, but you might want to take a look at veracrypt, which does a fantastic job at encrypting containers (they're files that you can mount as drives).